# Difference between two query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, difference

I have a question, it is possible to difference (mathematic operation) between two results?

Here is the code:

```
<?php 
$row = $query->row();
echo "<b>Your total expenses:</b><br />". $row->TotalExpense;
 ?>

<?php 
$row = $query2->row();
echo "<b>Your total incomes:</b><br />". $row->TotalIncome;
 ?>
```

Can I make something like:
TotalIncome - TotalExpense?

```
    <?php
$x = query2
$y = query1

echo $x - $y;
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes ofcourse you can, as long as you store the results in some variable that you can later use. You kinda answered your own question here.

Comment: @Loek, can you give me an example sir? I used CodeIgniter and the whole process is complicated.

Comment: `echo $x - $y;` You just wrote it there. Or are you asking how to get the value you want from a query? For that, the manual should give you the right answer

Comment: you are closing these, right? `$x = query2
$y = query1` - as in `$x = query2;
$y = query1;`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I believe this was just pseudo-code. I don't think `query1` is supposed to be a defined constant.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII One never knows nowadays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your start point is right. You kind of already had it.

```
<?php 
$TotalExpense = $query->row()->TotalExpense;
$TotalIncome = $query2->row()->TotalIncome;

echo "<b>Your Balance:</b><br />". ($TotalIncome - $TotalExpense);
 ?>
```

Comment: @funkyz0r so glad it works for you :) please don't hesitate to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$x = $row->TotalIncome;
$y = $row->TotalExpense;

echo "<b>Balance:</b><br />" . ($x - $y);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks but I have the two errors: Undefined property: stdClass::$TotalIncome and $TotalExpense.

Comment: @funkyz0r that's strange because it's the exact same usage you have posted in your example `$row->TotalIncome`, so your posted question should return the same errors. you must have placed the statements out of context.

Comment: @Jeff Pucket II Yes, sorry I've forget it, thanks Jeff :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$query1 = array(
  "TotalExpense" => 200.42
);

$query2 = array(
  "TotalIncome" => 500.42
);

$row1 = (object)$query1;
echo "<b>Your total expenses:</b>". $row1->TotalExpense ."<br />";

$row2 = (object)$query2;
echo "<b>Your total incomes:</b>". $row2->TotalIncome ."<br />";

echo "<b>Your balance:</b>". ($row2->TotalIncome - $row1->TotalExpense) ."<br />";
```

Results in this output

```html
<b>Your total expenses:</b>200.42<br /><b>Your total incomes:</b>500.42<br /><b>Your balance:</b>300<br />
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff, but I already have the values for TotalExpense and TotalIncome calculated with a query from MySQL.

Comment: @funkyz0r those were simply stand-ins for reproducible demonstration of a source of data. the punch line solution is `($row2->TotalIncome - $row1->TotalExpense)` which I'm sure you've figured out by now.